# Sqlite how delete last added entry of a table

Tags: sqlite, sql-delete

I'm trying to delete the last added entry of a table:

```
DELETE FROM notes ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
```

This just causes the following error:

```
near "ORDER": syntax error
```

Why might I be getting this error? (`notes` exists and has records in it!)

Comment: is created_at a column you define?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this

```
DELETE FROM notes WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM notes);
```

Comment: What if I don't have an `id` column?

Comment: There is always a id .. it is called rowid or ROWID and is automatically assigned,

Answer (score 2):

```
delete from notes where created_at = ( select max(created_at) from notes );
```

Watch out, this will not limit the number of rows deleted. If there are more than one row at max(created_at), this will delete all of them because the subject you specified does not exist (last added entry of a table).

Comment: Thats the solution for me! Thanks for your hint! I just use the max(id) to make sure, that there is really just the last entered id...